# Mapear SP de ORACLE que me retorna un cursor

Tags: entity-framework, oracle-10g

por favor necesito su ayuda para terminar de armar una arquitectura. Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente:

Crear al SP de ORACLE los CRUD, todo esta facil, el principal problema que tengo es que para los select hago algo como:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE BI.P_CAMARAS_ARQ
(
    I_COD_EMPRESA   IN  VARCHAR2,
    I_NUM_CUENTA    IN  NUMBER,
    O_SALDOS        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
IS
BEGIN
    OPEN O_SALDOS FOR
    select cod_camara COD_CAMARA, descripcion DESCRIPCION from BI.ACH_CAMARA;
END P_CAMARAS_ARQ;
```

Y a la hora de importar la función desde EF no me aparece el generar tipo complejo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eliminar alerta
|
Editar
|
Eliminar
|
Cambio de tipo
Question
No puede votar su propia entrada
0

Bueno entiendo que por ser un cursor el dato de resultado, debe definir unas lineas en el `APP.config`, indicando ciertos parametros, yo lo hice asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero de todas maneras no me permite generar el tipo complejo en base a las columnas del cursor.

Alguien sabe que mas tengo que hacer, ya estoy 2 dias sufriendo con este tema.

Nota. Utilizo VS2015, EF 6, Oracle 10g, EDMX.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: En el app.config puse lo siguiente:

Comment: Y actualizas la pregunta con el app.config que mencionas en vez de ser un comentario? Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Deberias validar este artículo

[Entity Framework, LINQ and Model-First for the Oracle Database](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm)

Alli se menciona

> Note: If these stored procedures do not appear, make sure that you added them earlier in the OBE - INCREASE_SALARY_BY_10, UPDATE_AND_RETURN_SALARY and OUTPARAM in the HR schema under Procedures

Valida que hayas agregado el `OUTPARAM` seguramente en tu caso se llame `O_SALDOS`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Leandro, pero en el articulo el OUTPARAM es el nombre de un SP de la BD, en mi caso O_SALDOS es el nombre del Cursor de Salida del SP, cuales la relación?

Comment: Ahora que lo veo en detalle veo que si es un procedure, me confundio el nombre que le asigno, pense que se trataba de un tipo definido que usaba como salida y necesitaba ser seleccionado

Comment: Si creas un modelo nuevo en un proyecto de ejemplo y seleccionas la misma db Oracle incluyendo el procedure tienes el mismo problema

Comment: Sip tengo el mismo problema, cree varios proyectos de diferentes tipo de diferentes maneras y en ninguno logro que me reconozca el tipo de dato de salida para generar el tipo complejo.